# docker-compose up is forcing me to update my dockerfile

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have fairly limited experience in docker and I've been trying to run
`docker-compose build` on a project I need to run. I'm using docker in windows 10.

The build has been stopping every few seconds and has been giving me different errors, like:

`W: The repository 'http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates Release' does not have a Release file.` when running  `RUN apt-get update`,

`E: Unable to locate package mysql-client` when running `RUN apt-get -y install mysql-client`

etc.

While I have been able to solve the former error, I've been trying to get it to install mysql-client for a while now and It just keeps throwing one error or another, despite the changes I've made to the dockerfile. (I've tried changing the line to `RUN apt-get -y install default-mysql-client`)

This is my dockerfile:

```
FROM node:10

RUN echo "UTC" > /etc/timezone
RUN dpkg-reconfigure -f noninteractive tzdata

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get -y install mysql-client

RUN mkdir /usr/homework1
RUN mkdir /usr/homework2
RUN mkdir /usr/homework3
```

My question is, why is this happening? I built the same project on ubuntu about a year ago and it worked just fine. Is there a way to stop it from giving me so many errors? The project has about 10 containers, will I need to go step by step on every single dockerfile? Is it because of the docker-compose version? I'm currently using

> Docker Compose version v2.23.0-desktop.1

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include your `Dockerfile`

Comment: done, it's a fairly simple dockerfile, that's why I'm confused on how I'm getting so many errors

Comment: `docker-compose` is used for v1, you should use `docker compose` - https://docs.docker.com/compose/migrate/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `node:10` image is old and based on Debian 9 (called 'stretch'). Support for Debian 9 stopped in 2022. That's why the package manager can't find the packages you want to install.

Node 10 is also out of support since 2021.

You should move to a newer version of Node and Debian. The latest LTS version of Node is version 20, so that might be a good candidate. To use it, change your `FROM` statement to

```
FROM node:20
```

That image uses Debian 12 (called 'bookworm') which will be supported until 2028.

Answer (score 1):

If for some reason you still want to use `node:10` even though it is no longer supported, add it before the RUN apt-get update

```
RUN sed -i -e 's/deb.debian.org/archive.debian.org/g' \
           -e 's|security.debian.org|archive.debian.org/|g' \
           -e '/stretch-updates/d' /etc/apt/sources.list
```